# How to re-size a part of a sprite?

Tags: css

I need to re-size a given area of a sprite. My original image is 800px by 200px. I set `background-position: 200px 0px;` and `width: 100px; height: 25px;` This gives me the correct part of the sprite, but I am wondering if it is possible to re-size this portion of the sprite to say 200px by 50px. But `background-size: 200px 50px;` resizes the whole sprite to this size, not just the area I am interested in.

Thanks!

I am trying to be general, so there is no fiddle.

Comment: Sorry, but not possible

Comment: Can you edit the sprite to include the larger image?  I would try experimenting with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using percentages to scale the image proportionately. For example, to double that portion to 200px by 50px, use:

```
background-size: 200% 200%;
```

This resizes the background to [200% of the width and height of its container](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size) respectively. You may need to adjust the `background-position` value to accommodate this method of scaling, depending on your layout or use case.

Be aware that `background-size` isn't really designed for use with sprites, so this may or may not achieve the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't scale a portion of an image using CSS.  I tested `background-size` by percentage and was surprised to find that the scaling on Chrome is not 1:1.

`background-size: 50%` doubled the background image.  With `200%` it seemed to scale exponentially.

http://jsfiddle.net/qFCk3/

Comment: This behavior is by design. See the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size) (which I've gone ahead and linked to in my answer). It's not 50% or 200% of the image's intrinsic dimensions, but 50% or 200% of the container.

Comment: Makes perfect sense now. Thanks